# Regex particular order of characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble of RegEx in the java programming language. I'm not quite sure if I need something else, but here is my question:

I want to check a particular string contains any letter followed by any 4 numbers.

I've been tinkering with it for a while and am having a bit of trouble. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is very easy. What have you tried?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: Go to http://www.regexr.com/ on the left side there is an example section. And lots of explanation try it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, match a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) of any letter, followed by a character class of any number [repeated 4 times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gO2pP0)

---

FYI, I included the 3 links because those are good resources for you to learn.  This is a very simple task and if you do some reading you'll pick up on regular expressions quicker than you would think.

Answer (score 2):

Well depending on your definition of *particular* string, you can use either the [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) function which matches your regular expression against the whole string or [`Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) if you want to search for a pattern somewhere within a string.

You can use the following regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}
```

Regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]        any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
[0-9]{4}        any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
```

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression you want is `\p{L}\d{4}` since `\p{L}` is a POSIX class that means "letter", and `\d` means digit.  This has the advantage of catching letters in languages other than English, which `[a-zA-Z]` won't.  See the [Pattern Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.

To write this expression as a `String` literal, you'd use `"\\p{L}\\d{4}"`.  To find it in a `String`, you could use the `matches` method, and add `.*` to the start and the end, like this.

```
if (myString.matches(".*\\p{L}\\d{4}.*")) {
    // Do something
}
```